# When to omit "as" in the cases below?

Tags: complementation

The problem puzzling me:

1)

> " I consider him a good person "

or

> " I consider him as a good person"

2)

> " I was appointed  commander "

or

> " I was appointed as commander "

Answer (score 1):

The verb pattern verb + someone + object complement is a bit confusing as to the use or drop of "as".

1 One group in this pattern are verbs such as to elect, appoint + someone + rank/title/position. These verbs are generally used without "as". Sometimes "as" or another preposition is also possible.

Examples
They appointed him captain of our team.They elected him (as) treasurer. They made him our trainer.

Verbs of this group are

to appoint, choose (as/for), crown, declare, elect (as), make, proclaim.

2 A second group of verbs uses the prep as or for:

to acknowledge as, recognize as, look upon as, regard as, speak/talk of someone as, think of as

to take someone for, mistake someone for

3
to consider is usually used without as, but it can occur occasionally: They considered her an excellent teacher.

Source: My old school grammar from the sixties by Sutton/Beilhardt, Klett Verlag.

When in doubt about the verb construction in this verb pattern I recommend
consulting Oald.

Answer (score 0):

I consider him a good friend

I consider him as a good friend.

Both the sentences are grammatical, but the former is far more common and idiomatic.  The use of "as" after consider is becoming less and less common.

I was appointed (as) commander.

The use of "as' is optional; you can use or leave it, without any difference in meaning.

Answer (score -1):

For 1), both are possible, but the former sounds more natural.

> I consider him a good person.

For 2), *appoint* should be used with *as*, so the latter is correct, but you should add an article in front of *commander*.

> I was appointed as a commander.